# Embedded Google Map blank iframe

Tags: google-maps

I had this embedded map working just fine and now suddenly it just shows a blank iframe. I don't think I made any changes...what the heck?

http://valleychristianschool.ca/contact.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your link has become corrupted with escaped HTML. Halfway through your link it reads:

```
;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;...
```

instead of:

```
;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"</iframe>
```

Comment: Doh! I should have seen that. Thanks for finding my mistake.